# Individual versus group-wise significance in ARDL context

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, ardl

In an ARDL model approach, what is one supposed to do if the F-bound test shows insignificance while some variables have significant long run and short run coefficients (the error correction term is negative and significant)?

1. Is the model useless?
2. Can I still say that I have long-run relationship for the significant variables?
3. Can I say that I have short run relationship?

Comment: Dave Giles has an extensive blog post ["ARDL Models - Part II - Bounds Tests"](http://davegiles.blogspot.no/2013/06/ardl-models-part-ii-bounds-tests.html) covering bounds test in ARDL. Could it be useful?

Comment: Also, you may check out the comments under that post (there are over 300 of them), perhaps one or more incidentally addresses your question.

Comment: yea I read that article + comments and I cant find the answer. Thanks anways

Comment: I found some papers now where they actually only look at the ECM term ex:

"Trade-GDP Nexus in Iran:An Application of the Autoregressive Distributed Lag (ARDL) Model" (2005)

However in all other papers related to ARDL, its never an discussion about this and the authors often claim that if the F-statistic is insignificant there is no longrun relationship. 

So I have conflicting results.

Comment: @RichardHardy I see that you created `[ardl]` tag and re-tagged multiple questions using it. It would be great if next time you didn't re-tag so many questions at once so not to flood the main page with re-tagged Q's. Moreover, could you please add tag wiki to it so it is clear that does "ARDL" stands for? Thanks.

Comment: @Tim, I have created the Wiki and the excerpt immediately after creating the tag. But I do not have sufficient reputation to do that independently, so they had to be reviewed. This took a while. Now there was low traffic at the moment, so I used the chance to retag questions instead of waiting for a more busy time. Perhaps I should have retagged fewer than that, but I think it was easy to see what was going on when looking at active questions, so people would just go back a bit further than usual. But thanks for taking an interest!